# Vypython: AttributeError: 'box' object has no attribute 'idx'

Tags: python-3.x, 3d, attributeerror, vpython

I am new to vpython and trying to learn. However, right after installing the module with "pip install vpython" and making a python file that contains this :

```
from vpython import *
box()
```

I am greeted with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/remis/Downloads/Test Vpython.py", line 2, in <module>
    box()
  File "C:\Users\remis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 1099, in __init__
    super(box, self).setup(args)
  File "C:\Users\remis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 579, in setup
    super(standardAttributes, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Users\remis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 236, in __init__
    from .no_notebook import _
  File "C:\Users\remis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vpython\no_notebook.py", line 271, in <module>
    __w = threading.Thread(target=__server.serve_forever)
NameError: name '__server' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function standardAttributes.__del__ at 0x00000182B9D4EAF0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\remis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 1092, in __del__
    super(standardAttributes, self).__del__()
  File "C:\Users\remis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 317, in __del__
    cmd = {"cmd": "delete", "idx": self.idx}
AttributeError: 'box' object has no attribute 'idx'
```

I don't see any help online, can I get some please?

Comment: Please post this on the VPython forum, https://groups.google.com/g/vpython-users and include details of how you launch VPython.

Comment: This code runs fine for my vpython install to a Python 3.9 virtual environment on my machine. I agree with @user1114907's advice too.